# Jquery template href click

Tags: jquery, href, jquery-templates

I have this href in a jquery template how could i make it that when this is clicked it will go to a javascript function?

```
<a href="#" id="number" class="rowSelection btn_simple" data-url="/Marketing/Moby/SelectPhoneNumber" data-redirect="/Marketing/Moby" data-value="${PhoneNumber}">Select</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this `<a href="#"` with this: `<a href="yourfunction()"`

or **even better** you can leave the html as it is and add it on the jQuery like:

```
$('#number').click(function(e){
//your code here
});
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qhJJm/)**

Comment: neither worked... when i changed the # it tried to redirect to another page... and the second one just plain did not work.

Comment: @CoreyToolis, do you have jQuery loaded in your scripts and added id="number" to the a tag? did you get any console error?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="yourfunction();return false;" id="number" class="rowSelection btn_simple" data-url="/Marketing/Moby/SelectPhoneNumber" data-redirect="/Marketing/Moby" data-value="${PhoneNumber}">Select</a><br/>
or 
$(document).on("click", "#number", function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // function body
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `href="#"` with `href="yourFunction();"`:

```
<a href="yourFunction();" id="number" class="rowSelection btn_simple" data-url="/Marketing/Moby/SelectPhoneNumber" data-redirect="/Marketing/Moby" data-value="${PhoneNumber}">Select</a><br/>
```

or this:

```
$("#number").click(function() {
    // Your function
});
```